# Android How should one behave when setting Android App Version

Tags: android, version-control

I noticed that Facebook Messenger App has 138.0.9.80 as version number. 
In my App, I hardcoded my app version to 1.0 in `AndroidManifest`
Is there a mechanism to change version number automatically as soon as the App is updated ? I mean, 138.0.9.80 is surely not hardcoded. Or is this a subjective decision concerning minor updates, fixes etc? How does the version system in Android works, when you publish an app?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning.html

Comment: In short-  138.0.9.80 is hard coded in their manifest, although their build system bumps it automatically.  You can name your versions whatever you want, including never changing it if that's your preference.  What is controlled is the version number, which is a monotonically increasing integer (although what it increases by each release is up to you).  The Play Store/Android OS only use the number for any purpose other than display.